# yii createcommand not working for cron

Tags: php, yii

I have created a croncommand and used sql statement in a function but when i am running it by using command `php protected/yiic cron` ,it throws error:

> exception 'CException' with message 'CConsoleApplication and its
>   behaviors do not have a method or closure named "createCommand".' in
>   /home/sbl13/public_html/atp/yii/framework/base/CComponent.php:266

My function is

```
public function actionSendFeedbackReminder()
{
  $sql = "SELECT training.id,session.trainingid,
   group_concat(session.id),min(c_startdate) AS start,
   max(c_enddate) AS end,training.programid,catalog.title
   FROM training JOIN session ON 
   session.trainingid=training.id 
   JOIN catalog ON catalog.id=training.catalogueid
   WHERE training.active=1 and session.active=1 
   GROUP BY trainingid"; // query to get data from databse
  $data = Yii::app()->createCommand($sql)->queryAll(); //throws error here
}
```

I am not getting any help from google

Answer (score 1):

[`createCommand`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#createCommand-detail) is a function of `CDbConnection` and not of `CConsoleApplication`. Your code should read:

```
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```